# Getting the complete Cell expression some input would generate as output

Tags: front-end, output-formatting

I can think of calling `Print` and then `SelectionMove` to copy the expression and then delete it. Is there any more transparent way?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that `ToBoxes` (or possibly `MakeBoxes`) does what you want.  You would need to wrap the result in a valid `Cell` expression like this:

```
celldata = Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ #, "Output"] &;

Sqrt[2^x] // celldata
```

> ```
> Cell[BoxData[SqrtBox[SuperscriptBox["2", "x"]]], "Output"]
> ```

Comment: Nice one. Do you understand why the output is different for code such as `celldata[TeXForm[2]]`?

Comment: @Rojo please, how is it different?

Comment: Well, the actual cell output is `Cell["2", "Output",..]` and the reesult of the `ToBoxes` func is `Cell[BoxData[
  InterpretationBox["\"2\"", TeXForm[2], Editable -> True, 
   AutoDelete -> True]], "Output"]`. Other forms also get some extra boxes that don't appear in the real output

Comment: @Rojo that appears to be a change from v7 to v8.  What do you get with `MakeBoxes` rather than `ToBoxes`?

Comment: The same, no difference

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get any cell as a Mathematica structure, not just one you recently created, you can use `NotebookGet` (or just plain `Get` for a notebook file you don't have open) and then pick out the particular cell you want using `Cases`, `Part` or `Extract`. The first is particularly useful if you want pick out a bunch of cells at once, based on some common attribute (like their cell style). I find this is generally much more convenient than trying to do stuff with `SelectionMove` and the like.

If you aren't trying to do this programmatically, and just want to see the expression for a *specific cell*, you can just select the cell, and go to the "Cell" menu, and select the "Show Cell Expression" option.